# Filtering dictionary values

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary:

```
 {'INF_Test': ['mi-0e6d869b68d49c2c4', 0, 0], 'INF_Test2': [0, 'mi-0a5d9089f493ae12a', 'mi-04506ea0d2810d3d5']}
```

I want to remove all the zeroes from the lists to get something like the following:

```
 {'INF_Test': ['mi-0e6d869b68d49c2c4'], 'INF_Test2': ['mi-0a5d9089f493ae12a', 'mi-04506ea0d2810d3d5']}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension and a dictionary comprehension:

```py
{key: [item for item in value if item != 0] for key, value in data.items()}
```

This outputs:

```py
{
 'INF_Test': ['mi-0e6d869b68d49c2c4'],
 'INF_Test2': ['mi-0a5d9089f493ae12a', 'mi-04506ea0d2810d3d5']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aaa = {'INF_Test': ['mi-0e6d869b68d49c2c4', 0, 0], 'INF_Test2': [0, 'mi-0a5d9089f493ae12a', 'mi-04506ea0d2810d3d5']}
for key in aaa.keys():
    aaa[key] = list(filter(lambda num: num != 0, aaa[key]))

print(aaa)
```

Output

```
{'INF_Test': ['mi-0e6d869b68d49c2c4'], 'INF_Test2': ['mi-0a5d9089f493ae12a', 'mi-04506ea0d2810d3d5']}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here's an opportunity to use *filter()*:

```
d = {'INF_Test': ['mi-0e6d869b68d49c2c4', 0, 0], 'INF_Test2': [0, 'mi-0a5d9089f493ae12a', 'mi-04506ea0d2810d3d5']}

e = {k : list(filter((0).__ne__, v)) for k, v in d.items()}
```